# how does ES6 resolve import paths and can we customize its behavior

Tags: path, ecmascript-6

How can we customize a root directory to be the `/`, seems like this behavior is entirely depending on the relative path of the current file.

For example, I would prefer to use a couple of directory paths

- src
- style
- components

and in deep nested direcotry `components/header/navbar.js`, i want to import without initialy slashes something like:

```
import Blah from 'src/models/Blah'
```

but instead I have to do

```
import Blah from '../../src/models/Blah'
```

Answer (score 2):

The *module identifier* is completely opaque to ECMAScript. I.e. there are no rules in the language about how it should be interpreted. The module identifier is interpreted by the *module loader* (and in the broader context, the *environment*) or the *module bundler* you are using.

E.g. Node's rules for interpreting module identifiers can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) and these are the rules that most bundlers that work with Node modules support.

But many bundlers provide ways to customize this.

Summary: How to do this and whether it is possible to do this depends on the environment/module loader/module bundler you are using. It has nothing to do with the language itself.

---

Related questions:

- Webpack: [Resolving require paths with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27502608/218196)
- Node.js: [Avoid using relative paths on require()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27393356/218196)

Answer (score 1):

If you use webpack to compile ES2015 codes,
you can use **resolve** field in webpack.config.js to select default path

```
resolve: {
  modules: [path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app'), 'node_modules'],
},
```

such like above. In above case, webpack will handle **/app** directory as root.